# how to add json object?

Tags: json, rest

I have the following person in JSON:
{name: "John", age: 20}
I would like to add another person so that I have a total of:
{name: "John", age: 20},
{name: "Eva", age: 15}

How would I go about doing this using JavaScript and xmlhttprequest? Would I use PUT or POST when adding the 2nd person, Eva? If REcreating (using POST), would I need to save the first person, John, in a variable, and then append the 2nd person, Eva, and then POST? If so, how would adding a person to a list of 1000 persons be handled? Thank you!

Comment: For creating a new person usually, we use `POST` as a method, `PUT` will be used in case of update. Even when we need to create an N number of records we can use `POST` by sending the array of data to backend. 


PS: This is a common convention, in your case we have to see how its implemented. Not necessarily to be like this.

Comment: This does not quite answer my question. I understand POST is for creating a new person or record.  I understand PUT is used for updating.  However, my main question is, what if we have N records and need to add an additional one.  Do we use PUT (update) or POST (create an entire new record holding N+1 records)?  If we use POST, do we grab all N records and store them somewhere (in a variable?), add one more record, and then we do POST?  How is that implemented? I've provided an easy example on my question. Thank you.

Comment: As per the example, each new user object should be a new record. So if we already have `N or zero` records in the database, no need to fetch all to the front end and update list and send that back to the backend to update DB. Instead, we should be sending just the new record, in this case `{name: "Eva", age: 15}`, using POST and backend should be adding the new item into the DB.